bpy: handlers.save_pre not updating immediately before saving
This script is to update  a property to its relative path when the file is saved, however how it is currently set up, the property does not update until a few seconds after the save. Even worse, if I close the file before it shows the update and try to reopen it, the file will crash.
If there is a way to ensure stability or another approach to keeping filepaths relative, please share. Thank you.
import bpy

def rel_path_on_save(scene):
    props = bpy.context.scene.props
    path, _ = bpy.path.relpath(props.dir_path)
    if path:
        props.dir_path = path

class Props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    dir_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Folder",
        description="Export from the chosen collections",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default='//'
    )

def draw_export_panel(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    props = context.scene.props
    layout.prop(props, "dir_path")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Props)
    bpy.types.Scene.props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Props)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(rel_path_on_save)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_tools_object.append(draw_export_panel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Props)
    del bpy.types.Scene.props
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(rel_path_on_save)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_tools_object.remove(draw_export_panel)

# Run script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

